# how a 32 bit processor process 64 bit double value?

Tags: java

Any body tell me how a 32 bit processor do the operations on 64 bit double  values?

In java double is 64 bit long. Then how a 32 bit processor do arithametic operations(ie. addidion or subtraction) upon 64 bit double variables.

Comment: What's the relatin to javascript?

Comment: Related question: How can you add arbitrary numbers using only 10 digits?

Comment: The answer for Java will be different from the answer for C will be different from the answer for JavaScript, most likely, because of the presence/absense of virtual machines and JIT, and the degree to which the VM and/or JIT'd code use the CPU or coprocessor's instruction set for it.

Comment: The JVM will certainly use the FPU of your CPU if it has one available (which CPU doesn't have one nowadays?)

Comment: X86 CPUs have got a 80-bit(`long double`) float registers, and even more MMX registers 128-bit, and even more AVX1,2 registers (256-512) :D

Comment: @Thomas
how 32 bit browser process 64bit double precesion numbers. That is my real doubt ie why I add javascript.

Comment: @parsaporahmad This key piece of information should constitute the essence of the correct answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

64 bit types and their operations are **emulated** on 32 bit processors. Upon compilation the compiler maps the 64 bit values to two 32 bit values, and the operations upon these values to a sequence of operations on their 32 bit representations. That means that a simple operation which adds two 64 bit values can be executed natively and atomic on a 64 bit CPU, takes a few clock cycles when being emulated on a 32 bit CPU.

Details and examples: [64-bit types and arithmetic on 32-bit CPUs](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/10/21/64-bit-types-and-arithmetic-on-32-bit-cpus/)

Answer (score 2):

The numeric co-processor, who does the floating point operations doesn't care about whether the main CPU is 32bit or 64bit.

Comment: how much bit a co-processor will be??

Comment: @AlexMathew 32/64 usually, at least if it is IEEE conform.

Answer (score 1):

The 32-bit CPU simply deals with 64-bit `long` (or the co-processor int the case of `double`)  numbers in two 32-bit pieces, with registers that automatically detect and notify on overflows, *etc*.

Comment: Could you explain the internal processing a 64 bit data.